# Creating a datetime array with x seconds interval between cells in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to use datetime to create an array the will start at:

```
2018-7-16 9:00:00
```

and will have 150 seconds interval for 3000 times, so the results will be an array with 3000 cells that looks like this:

```
2018-7-16 9:00:00
2018-7-16 9:02:30
2018-7-16 9:05:00
....
```

I've tried:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

interval = 150
base = datetime(2018,7,16,9,0,0)
arr = numpy.array([base + timedelta(seconds=interval) for i in range(3000)])
```

but the result is:

```
rray([datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16, 9, 2, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16, 9, 2, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16, 9, 2, 30), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16, 9, 2, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16, 9, 2, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16, 9, 2, 30)], dtype=object)
```

Any ideas or a better way to do this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be

```
numpy.array([base + timedelta(seconds=interval * i) for i in range(3000)])
#                                              ^^^
```

Comment: It worked, how I missed that I don't know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.date_range("2018-7-16 9:00:00", freq="150S", periods=3000).values
```